# Trying to keep TextSize similar for all screen sizes

Tags: android, out-of-memory, drawtext, text-size

So I need a piece of advice. I have a small game that is timed and for the last 5 seconds I want it to display the time remaining in the background( aka countdown: 5 4 3 2 1). Previously I just made large images of the numbers so that it was easy to scale all the images to different screen sizes. Now I am running out of room in the buffer (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget) So I want to use drawText to put the numbers in the background, but I need it to scale to the entire screen for every device. Any Suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks
-Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use "sp" or scale-independent pixels. See more information on what they are and how to use them here: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I dont think I understand. I tried doing it like this:

           private static final float GESTURE_THRESHOLD_SP = 500.0f;
         final float scale =     getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    scalenumber= (int) (GESTURE_THRESHOLD_SP * scale + 0.5f);
    p.setTextSize(scalenumber);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawText("5",width/9,height*9/10,p);

It didnt work, I tried it on my device and an emulator and they showed up in different spots. Any help? 
Also, how do I keep the positioning similar for both? Thanks